# VS Code settings.json is ignored by Eslint when trying to set custom .eslintrc.js path

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I'm trying to set up a custom `eslintrc.js` for my workspace using the `settings.json` in VS Code with this (I've tried many options):

```json
{
    "prettier.configPath": ".vscode/.prettierrc",
    "eslint.options": {
        "configFile": ".vscode/.eslintrc.js",
        "overrideConfigFile": ".vscode/.eslintrc.js"
    },
    "eslint.lintTask.options": "-c ~/.eslintrc.js"
}
```

but it seems that no matter what I do the neither `~/.eslintrc.js` nor `.vscode/.eslintrc.js` is picked up.

My problem is that the project has some formatting settings that make it unreadable for me and I'd like to have my own `.prettierrc` config for local development. This already works, but ESlint conflicts with this as it uses the `.prettierrc` file that's in the root folder.

A solution for this is to just remove `"plugin:prettier/recommended"` from the `extends` list in my `.eslintrc.js` file (this is why I'm trying to supply my own `.eslintrc.js` file), but it won't budge. What am I doing wrong?